# Click button with same label in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario: I have 4 buttons each with the same label but different "value" how would do I select a certain button under the same label but with a certain value?

For other 3 buttons have the same as above but just different text like Detached is Semi-Detached for example and the value="129".

How do I for example select the above button with the value 128?

Also these buttons arent visible until a certain button is clicked. My scripts will always click this button to make these buttons visible but even then I still cant select them using simple ID/CSSSelector/Xpath by right clicking and copying them into code, they do not work.

Iv tried using this:

```
[2]/label[@for='SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond']
```

But no success.

Inspection:

```
<div class="form-group mg-between property-type-two-follow-up" rdg-loading-indicator="suppress" style="">
<div class="row" data-toggle="buttons">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 btn-group">
            <label for="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" class="btn btn-default btn-block  ">
                <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond must be a number." id="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" name="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" type="radio" value="127">
                Semi-Detached
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 btn-group">
            <label for="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" class="btn btn-default btn-block  ">
                <input id="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" name="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" type="radio" value="128">
                Detached
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 btn-group">
            <label for="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" class="btn btn-default btn-block  ">
                <input id="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" name="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" type="radio" value="129">
                Terraced
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 btn-group">
            <label for="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" class="btn btn-default btn-block  ">
                <input id="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" name="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" type="radio" value="130">
                Link-Detached
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 btn-group">
            <label for="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" class="btn btn-default btn-block  ">
                <input id="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" name="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" type="radio" value="131">
                Dorma
            </label>
        </div>
    <input id="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" name="SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond" type="hidden" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an XPath selector by name and value? Something like:

//input[@name='SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond' and @value='128']

Also, Selenium won't click on hidden elements. After you do whatever action that shows these elements, try introducing a sleep, something like Thread.Sleep(1000) to give a bit of time for the elements to be shown.

*Edit:* I agree with the comment below, waiting for a fixed amount of time is not the most elegant solution. You could use a WebDriverWait, something like this:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
var element = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='SelectedTypeOfPropertySecond' and @value='128']")).Displayed);
```

I used a 15 sec timeout there, but you can use a higher value if you expect the element to take more than 15 secs to display.

*Edit 2*: As Metareven said in his comment you could use the following line to define a 15 secs implicit wait when you get your driver's instance, so you just define it once:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
```

This will wait up to 15 secs whenever you look for a control in case it's not available yet.

Comment: i'd argue that waiting for an element to become visible would be better than thread.sleep since that is dependent on whatever runs on the host system and sometimes the timeout would not be sufficient.

Comment: I always recommend people to use implicit waits: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp 

This way you only need to set the timeout once and it will apply for most actions, which in most cases is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a standard CSS-elector like this:

```
"[value=<your value>]"
```

Also if you need to click a button for these to appear, just remember to set the implicit wait value on your selenium session to make sure it will wait for more than 0 seconds for the element to appear